# Unit-testing extensions for an 'external' program with pyunit

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

I'm struggling to know where to start with unittest, having read the dive-into-python tutorial and looked at http://pyunit.sourceforge.net/.

I've got a piece of analysis software (call it 'prog.exe') which uses python for its input decks.  I've started writing a python module which I'm going to import from that input deck to provide some useful functionality.  So, running one of these analyses will go like this:

`prog.exe inputdeck.py`

where `inputdeck.py` contains:

```
from mymodule import mystuff
```

So how do I set up and run tests on `mymodule`? Should the above be in a system call in a `setUp` method of the test, or what?

---

Ok - solution:

Don't use `unittest.main()` as that's the command line tool. Instead call the appropriate unittest methods directly as follows:

From the command line run:

```
prog.exe mytests.py
```

where `mytests.py` contains:

```
import unittest
# ... code to run the analysis which we'll use for the tests ...
# ... test definitions ...
suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(test_cases)
unittest.TextTestRunner().run(suite)
```

See example at http://docs.python.org/release/2.6.7/library/unittest.html#unittest.TextTestRunner

Answer (score 0):

Pyunit is a little bit outdated (2001), it is now completely included in python core distribution (http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html). You should start read this documentation, especially the [basic example part](http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html#basic-example).

To test your module you'll have to create a file, let's call it `mymodule_test.py` and put in it something like this :

```
import unittest
from mymodule import mystuff

class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
   def test_01a(self):
      """ test mystuff"""
      self.failUnless(mystuff.do_the_right_stuff())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

and run it with `python mymodule_test.py`

Comment: Yep, that's what the dive-into-python tutorial (which is also a bit outdated in places) says.  But if I do that, prog.exe never gets involved so I can't test the stuff in mymodule.  The problem I guess is that I want to call BOTH "python mymodule_test.py" and "prog.exe" from the command line, and I can't see how to disentangle that.